# Sitercore 9.2 Commerce install failing on Bootstrapping Commerce Services

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation

Receiving this error during the install. Any idea what needs to be done? Thanks in advance.

```
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
At C:\Projects\XC92 Deploy\MyDeploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1:93 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @params -ErrorAction Continue *>&1 | Te ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:17:09
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
At C:\projects\XC92 Deploy\Modules\InitializeCommerce\InitializeCommerce.psm1:101 char:5
+     Invoke-RestMethod $UrlCommerceShopsServicesBootstrap -TimeoutSec  ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Comment: check your commerce engine service logs and see what error is there? i got same issue on my local machine and solved it by disabling redis caching and compression in commerce engine config file.

Comment: The log has this error: BootStrapping Commerce Services: https://commerceshops.sc9.com/commerceops/Bootstrap()
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.At MyDeploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1:93 char:1 + Install-SitecoreConfiguration @params -ErrorAction Continue *>&1 | Te CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration. 
Redis section seems clear in the log. to try your solution: Which file and section do I edit?

Comment: New to commerce so would appreciate the location of the file and the key/value used to disable redis caching and compression. Thank you @Vipin

Comment: look into your CommerceShops\wwwroot\logs folder and find out error in logs, for settings look into CommerceShops\wwwroot\config.json file, restart app pool after changing the settings, also change  same settings in other commerce engine roles and restart their app pools as well.

Comment: When I try to access https://commerceshops.sc9.com I get following error: An error occurred while starting the application.
.NET Framework 4.8.3752.0 X64 v4.0.0.0    |   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting version 2.1.1-rtm-30846    |    Microsoft Windows 10.0.18362    |   Need help?

Comment: @vbgp kindly edit your question to include all of the relevant error messages in the question itself. Screenshots help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering for the sake of someone googling this error - I had a similar error an it helped me to update the Sql database name to have double slash “\” between the machine name and sql instance i.e. "MyComputer\SQLEXPRESS"